# IIS 7.5 JK connector to Tomcat

Tags: iis, tomcat, iis-7.5, mod-jk, tomcat7

I have many Tomcat servers working using an older 32-bit version of the isapi_redirect.dll where I set the Default Application Pool to Enable 32-Bit Applications.  On a client's server, they need to install another ISAPI under the same application pool that doesn't work with 32-bit.

I am attempting to update the isapi_redirect.dll to be 64-bit.  I downloaded the `tomcat-connectors-1.2.40-windows-x86_64-iis.zip` from [here](http://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/windows/).
I disabled the 32-bit support for the Default Application Pool and browsed to localhost.  Instead of getting an error, all I see is the IIS 7 Default Welcome page.  If I remove the isapi_redirect.dll from it's folder, I do not get an error. I would think this means that IIS isn't even trying to find the .dll.

Do I need to enable or change something else to allow 64-bit isapi filters for Tomcat?

I follow a setup similar to [this](http://jhmeier.de/2009/10/16/acitvating-the-isapi-redirect-for-tomcat-under-iis-7-5-w2k8-r2-64-bit/), except I have an isapi_redirect.properties file instead of a registry entry and the folders are different.  This works with my 32-bit isapi filter.  I did try the registry way with the 64 isapi filter and also had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work.
The issue was that I only replaced the DLL file itself and also Disabled the Default Application Pool's 32-bit mode.  When I did that it did not work.
I went back and removed the virtual directory, the ISAPI filter and the ISAPI and CGI restriction and restarted IIS.
After the restart I installed everything with the 64-bit ISAPI filter and it worked without the 32-bit mode enabled.
I did not change any of the configuration files, so it seems that removing all of the settings and re-configuring was the fix.